# How much time it takes to update google analytics reporting for event tracking?

Tags: google-analytics, onclick, eventtrigger, event-tracking

I have implemented onclick javascript code into my website on different places with different parameters like following:

```
onClick="ga('send', '_trackEvent', { eventCategory: 'Property Listing Search', eventAction: 'Property Listing Search button', eventLabel: 'Searchbuttonclicked', eventValue: 5});"
```

i want to know that how much time it will take to update the data of triggering respective events with respective category and action??

for now i don't want to create any goal for there onclick events..

Please let me know....
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight error in the code you posted. You should be using

```
ga('send', 'event', 'some category', 'some action', 'some label', 'some value');
```

You can check GA debugger to see if the event is sent in real time or check the Real Time reports, otherwise you need to wait up to 24 hours to see it in your standard reports.

Comment: @nuyen Sir, I updated your answer with value parameter containing number instead of string.

Comment: Thanks...let me see the effect... is it necessary to create goals in analytics account???

Comment: No you do not need to create goals.

Comment: Good job. Please close off this open item by either accepting this answer, or updating your question.